# array format in php issue

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like:

```
Array
(
   [name] => Linda
   [place] => stdClassObject
      {
        [country] => stdClassObject
           (
              [answer] => Spain
           )
       }
   [age] => 16
   [gender] => Array
      (
           [0] => female
      )
)
```

Now, I need to change the key "place" in the array in such a way that its either like:
[place] => Spain
or
[place] => Array
  (
       [0] => Spain
  )

Basically, I have to change it to the same format the other keys are in the array. Can anybody help me? I'm new to this.

Comment: $array['place'] = "Spain";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$arr['place'] = $arr['place']->country->answer
```

or your other way:

```
$arr['place'] = array( $arr['place']->country->answer )
```